# What is the correct way to add static file version in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am making a web app using Django. Currently, I have created a versions.py file in **myproject/myproject** directory. Using the template tag, I am getting the version of the static file which is added in versions.py file. But every time I changed the css and js file, manually I have to changed the version of the respective file.

**versions.py**

```
# css versions
base_css = 1.1
header_css = 1.1
footer_css = 1.1
base_js = 1.1
...
```

**Template Tag**

```
from myproject import versions

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def home_base_css():
    return versions.home_base_css
```

**In Template**

```
{% load static %} 
{% load template_tag_file_name %}

<link href="{% static 'css/home/base.css' %}?v={% home_base_css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage

Comment: There is no "correct" or "wrong" way, there are some possible solutions, it's up to you to choose one or another. Django has built-in solution for handling static file versions, have a look at the link above. Yours is fine though, DRY can be enhanced by moving some more code to template tags or something like that.